# Establishing a Basis for $F[x]/(f(x))$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

**Hypothesis:**

1. $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n \in F[x]$ s.t. $f(x)$ irreducible over field $F$.
2. $deg(f(x)) = n \ge 1$.
3. Let $V = (f(x)) \subset F[x]$.

**Goal:** Show that $\mathcal{B} = \{1 + V, x + V, x^2 + V, \ldots , x^{n-1} + V\}$ forms a basis for $E = F[x]/V$

**Attempt:**

1. **Linear Independence:** If this set weren't linearly independent, then a non-trivial $b_i \in F$ would satisfy

   $$
   b_0 + b_1x + \ldots + b_{n-1} x^{n-1} + V = 0 + V
   $$

But this would then imply that $b_0 + b_1x + \ldots + b_{n-1} x^{n-1}  \in 0 + V$. But this would contradict $V = (f(x))$ since it is impossible that $f(x)\,\,|\,\,b_0 + b_1x + \ldots + b_{n-1} x^{n-1}$ of strictly lower degree.

Now how would I show that this set spans $F[x]/V$?

Comment: Polynomial division.

Comment: What does a typical element of $F[x]/V$ look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, I think the answer to my own question is as follows:

**Spanning Set Argument:** Let $g(x) + V \in F[x]/V$.  If $deg(g(x)) < n$, then we are done.  So suppose that $deg(g(x)) \ge n$.  Use the fact that $F[x]$ allows for polynomial division to divide $f(x)$ into $g(x)$.  Obtain $g(x) = f(x) q(x) + r(x)$ for some $q(x), r(x) \in F[x]$ s.t. $deg(r(x)) < n$.  Since $deg(r(x)) < n$, we have that $r(x)$ is a linear combination of the elements of $\mathcal{B}$.  Furthermore, the polynomial $f(x) q(x) \in (f(x)) = V$.  Then $g(x) + V$ collapses to a linear combination of the elements of $\mathcal{B}$ as desired.

Comment: I'm going to upvote this answer, yet perhaps remarking the fact that $\;g(x)=r(x)\pmod V\iff g(x)+V=r(x)+V\in\Bbb F[x]/V\;$ can help to see things a little clearer. +1